# How to trigger pipeline if any 1 of x repos is merged to main branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, branch

I am using a locally hosted version of GitLab Omnibus, and I stay up to date with the most current versions.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

I have five repositories.  They are not in the same project, and they aren't sub-repo's, or anything like that.  They are across multiple Groups.  We'll call four of them `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`, and one of them `X`.

Each of `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`, have a `main` branch.  Whenever a merge request into `main` succeeds, I would like for `X` to run end-to-end tests on `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`.

I've found their multi-project, down-stream, up-stream, and a few other types of pipelines, but I haven't seen any example or reason to believe this would work natively with the conditional of:

```
if (any one of A, B, C, Ds merges to branch.main)
    run X
```

I know I could probably do this through gitlab api, and setting up some external code to pull it all together, but I was hoping gitlab had this logic built in.  TIA